Relations between the optimal solutions of two related Semi-Definite Programs.
In system theory, we often encounter Semi-Definite Programs (SDPs) with Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) constraints, such as those presented in this paper. I have introduced new variables based on the original decision variables and reformulated the LMIs using these new variables. Additionally, I have defined a similar SDP and, through simulation, identified relationships between their optimal solutions. I am now seeking mathematical proofs to substantiate these relationships. Further details will be provided below, and I would greatly appreciate any assistance in addressing my inquiry.
Consider following LMIs, where $ H \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+m) \times (n+m)} $ and $ W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ are decision variables ($0 < m \leq n$) and we have:
\begin{equation}
 H = \begin{bmatrix} H_{11} & H_{12} \\
 H_{12}^T & H_{22} \end{bmatrix}, H_{11} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, H_{22} \succ 0
 \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}
\end{equation}
Also, $ D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (n+m)} $ and $ C \succeq 0 $ are constant matrices. Additionally, in all equations, $ 0 $ represents zero matrices of appropriate dimensions.
\begin{aligned}
    & \quad H - \begin{bmatrix} W & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0, \\
    & \quad D^T \left(H_{11} - H_{12} H_{22}^{-1} H_{12}^T \right) D - H + C \succeq 0.
\end{aligned}
Suppose $ K \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times j} $ is a constant matrix with rank $ n $ and $ j = n + n \cdot m $. The matrix $ T \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+m) \times (j+m)} $ is constructed as:
\begin{equation}
T = \begin{bmatrix} K & 0 \\
 0 & I_m \end{bmatrix} 
 \end{equation}
Suppose there exists a matrix $ S \in \mathbb{R}^{j \times (j+m)} $ such that $ D \cdot T = K \cdot S $.
The new variable $ X \in \mathbb{R}^{(j+m) \times (j+m)} $ is defined as:
\begin{equation}
 X = T^{T} H T = \begin{bmatrix} X_{11} & X_{12} \\
 X_{12}^T & X_{22} \end{bmatrix} 
 \end{equation}
Thus, the following relationships are established between the submatrices of $ H $ and $ X $:
\begin{aligned}
    & X_{11} = K^T H_{11} K, \\
    & X_{12} = K^T H_{12}, \\
    & X_{22} = H_{22}.
\end{aligned}
If we multiply the above LMIs from the left and right by $ T^T $ and $ T $, respectively, we obtain:
\begin{equation}
X - \begin{bmatrix} K^T W K & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
S^T K^T \left(H_{11} - H_{12} H_{22}^{-1} H_{12}^T \right) K S - T^T H T + T^T C T \succeq 0 \Rightarrow \\
 S^T \left(X_{11} - X_{12} X_{22}^{-1} X_{12}^T \right) S - X + T^T C T \succeq 0
\end{equation}
Selecting the new variable $ V $ as $ V = K^T W K $, we construct two  SDPs as follows.
note: Using Schur complement property, the equivalent of second LMIs substituted.
First SDP:
\begin{aligned}
    & \max_{H, W} \operatorname{trace}(W) \\
    & \quad \text{subject to:} \\
    & \quad H - \begin{bmatrix} W & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0, \\
    & \quad \begin{bmatrix} D^T H_{11} D - H + C & D^T H_{12}\\ H_{12}^T D & H_{22} \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0. 
\end{aligned}
Second SDP:
\begin{aligned}
    & \max_{X, V} \operatorname{trace}(V) \\
    & \quad \text{subject to:} \\
    & \quad X - \begin{bmatrix} V & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0, \\
    & \quad \begin{bmatrix} S^T X_{11} S - X + T^T C T & S^T X_{12}\\ X_{12}^T S & X_{22} \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0.
\end{aligned}
My Question:
Let $ H^* $ and $W^*$ be the optimal solutions of the first SDP, and $ X^* $ and $V^*$ the optimal solution of the second SDP.
We define $Z^*$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
   {Z^*} = T^{T} H^* T = \begin{bmatrix} {Z}_{11}^* & 
   {Z}_{12}^* \\
   ({Z}_{12}^*)^T & {Z}_{22}^* \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Prove the following equalities:

$V^*= K^T W^* K$
$ ({X}_{22}^*)^{-1} \cdot ({X}_{12}^*)^T = ({Z}_{22}^*)^{-1} \cdot ({Z}_{12}^*)^T $

My Attempt:
I have tested numerous examples with $n \leq 6$ and $m \leq n$ using randomly generated $K$ and $D$ matrices, and in all cases, the equalities hold. However, I am uncertain how to establish a mathematical proof for these results.
Tips:

As shown in the paper, we have:
$W^*=H_{11}^*-H_{12}^* \cdot ({H}_{22}^*)^{-1} \cdot ({H}_{12}^*)^T$
$V^*=X_{11}^*-X_{12}^* \cdot ({X}_{22}^*)^{-1} \cdot ({X}_{12}^*)^T$



Any condition on $H_{22}$?

@KBS, yes, $H_{22} \succ 0$

The issue is that your change of variables is not bijective. So, the implication or the equivalence may not hold all the time.

Try to check the conditions for many random systems with larger dimensions than $n=2$ and $m=1$.

@KBS , I have tested numerous examples with $ n \leq 6 $ and $ m \leq n $ using randomly generated $K$  matrices, and in all cases, the equalities hold. If necessary, I can provide my MATLAB code for review.

Not sure if it helps, but the conclusion is wrong if $m=0$ and $n=1$ (i.e., the 1D-case).
The solution for $W$ becomes $C/(1-D^2)$, and the solution for $V$ becomes $T^2C/(1-S^2)$, as far as I can tell.

Also, as far as I can tell, the first problem is ill-defined if $C=0$ and $D=0$? Perhaps there are some additional assumptions that need to be taken here...

@Firavox , Thanks for your attention. We suppose $m>0$ and $C \neq 0$ and $D \neq 0$. Could you also find cases where they equalities hold?

Those conditions are still not enough: Let $D = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $C = \begin{pmatrix}c & 0\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, for any positive $c>0$. I'll let you check that the only solution to the constraints in your first problem is satisfies $H_{21}=H_{12}=0$, and $H_{11}=0$ or $H_{22}=0$. Now, $H_{11}=0$ would lead to $W=0$, whereas $H_{22}=0$ would leave $W$ unbounded...

Even assuming we take that as an optimum, this would mean $Z = \begin{pmatrix}K^2 H_{11} & 0\0 & H_{22}\end{pmatrix}$, which is not invertible if $H_{22}=0$, so your second conjecture can not be formulated.
My guess is that you would need to at least assume the constraints can be solved strictly, and that $D$ (and perhaps $C$?) need to have full rank.
As for an example where it holds: I guess you can choose $D$ to be square and invertible, then the variable transformation should be bijective.

@Firavox , This problem arises from engineering, where certain conditions are implicitly assumed.
Please pay close attention to the dimensions. The matrix $ D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (n+m)} $ is rectangular, so it cannot be equal to $ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 2 & 0 \ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right) $. Additionally, matrix $ C $ has the same dimensions as $ H \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+m) \times (n+m)} $.
As mentioned in the comments, $ H_{22} \succ 0 $.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
